# Translating "It runs in our blood" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am looking for the exact Latin equivalent of:

> It runs in our blood.

In this sentence `it` refers to `Literature`. So far, we have come to this one:

> *Currit in sanguine nostro*

Feel free to change the whole sentence if that will meet what I am looking for more closely. I want the translation to sound formal and official.

Comment: Your translation is technically correct, word for word, but doesn't make much sense. What's the thing that runs in your blood? That'll affect the Latin.

Comment: @Draconis  Thanks for the quick reply. I am looking for a formal sentence. It is literature. It refers to literature but i want the sentence to be exactly a meaningful translatiom of It runs in our blood.

Comment: @luchonacho Thanks for the reply. I have googled your sentence and according to google it means our blood flows. Do you mean the same? Or google may be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, "it runs in our blood" is an English idiom that doesn't translate perfectly into Latin. Off the top of my head I'd use a form of *ingignō* instead. (Also Google Translate is notoriously bad at Latin, don't trust it in general.)

Comment: @Draconis No I don't trust GT and that's why i am here. I just used it to get something in latin. I didn't get the part about ingigno. Would you please tell me your prefered translation?

Comment: @luchonacho this one is ok only If really my own sentence doesn't make sense in Latin. Bit i prefee this idiom in Latin.

Comment: In this sense all the classical example I've traced speak of the blood in terms of the blood-line. They all refer to the parents, or the tribe *gens. 'E Sanguine Gentis Nostrae Currit'* would get round that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "runs in the blood" is an English idiom, and as such, it doesn't necessarily make sense when translated word-for-word into Latin. Instead, I would phrase it slightly differently.

> *in nōs ingenitus*
>   instilled into us

*Ingenitus* is a difficult word to translate succinctly, but it refers to something that's a natural part of someone from birth, rather than something they've picked up later. In other words, something in the blood.

You could also keep the reference to "blood" directly:

> *in sanguinem nōstrum ingenitus*
>   instilled into our blood(line)

Like in English, *sanguis* can mean literal blood (the stuff in your veins) or a direct line of descent, as in "blood relatives".

The repetition of *in* is somewhat poetic, and in my opinion makes it sound better, as well as adding emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

In effect, you asking about one of the basic difficulties of translation between any two languages. It's important to recognise that either style or idiom, and sometimes both, have to be transformed. In order to accomplish this, a translation is often a compromise, and the answer by Draconis indicates this very well. I would, however, be bolder and look for something which equates to the sense behind what you need to translate.

Is it unavoidable to write of something running through our blood *as such*? To me, it seems that if you want to refer to something within your nature — if you like, something inborn, innate — you might avoid any reference to blood and the way it moves, and still achieve what you want.

Perhaps *res in nos innata*, 'a thing inborn to us' would be a suitable format. You could substitute a more particular noun for *res* to suit your context: *litterae* or *humanitas*, for example (remembering, of course, to maintain agreement between whatever you choose and its epithet).

Answer (score 2):

For "it runs in our blood", to me, the following seems fine:

> *in sanguine nostro fluit*

*Fluit* emphasises the liquid aspect of blood more than *currit*.

Another option is "it runs inside our blood", as in:

> *intra sanguinem nostrum fluit*

Or "it runs through our blood":

> *per sanguinem nostrum fluit*