# What is the difference between ingenitus and innatus?

Tags: word-comparison, participle

When [discussing things "running in the blood"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7141/406), I suggested the word *ingenitus* for "innate", while Tom Cotton preferred *innatus*.

Is there a difference in meaning between these two words? The second one is clearly the origin of English "innate", via French.

EDIT: I'm specifically referring to the versions of these words meaning "innate" (prefixed with *in-* "in"), not the versions meaning "not having been born" (prefixed with *in-* "not").

Comment: I was remarking that it is sometimes necessary to transform the idiom into something else with the same effect and meaning. I would not, personally, refer to blood at all in this instance.

Comment: @TomCotton Agreed wholeheartedly! My mind had immediately gone to *ingignō* while you went with *innascor*, so now I'm curious if there's a difference between them, given that they both refer to something inherent from birth.

Answer (score 2):

Literally *innatus* is 'in-born' and *ingenitus* is 'begotten.'

In favour of *ingenitus* is the idea of a bloodline, a family continuity.

> 'claro sanguine genitus' Seneca Tragedies

source Dictionarium novum Latino-Gallicum, etc
By Gui TACHARD (free e-book)also Ainsworth (Archive facsimile)

But the bigger problem in answering this question is scientific. When Harvey argued the case for the circulation of the blood round the heart/ lungs/ limbs, rather than and push and pull within the body 'flow' took on a new meaning. In classical Latin the flow of blood is copious (Caesar, Livy) but it is always out of the gashes and wounds of battle and treachery, and over the face, onto bodies, the earth.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, both ingenitus and innatus are found only in Christian authors, when debating things like whether the Holy Ghost is born or unborn. I am not able to perceive any difference in meaning, but perhaps there is some theological distinction that escapes me. Both are transparent derivatives of genitus (ppp. of gigno) and (g)natus (ppp. of nascor) respectively, themselves from the same root, IE full-grade *ǵen(H)- and zero-grade *ǵn(H)-, though they are of course separate words in Latin.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, I mean the versions with *in-* "in" as opposed to *in-* "not": the participles from *ingignō* and *innascor*. For example, L&S cites Suetonius Nero 1 talking about _vitia ingenita_, "inherent flaws".

Comment: May I just point out that _ingenuus_ is more akin to _innatus_ than _ingenitus_? And that all three occur in properly Classical authors (Cicero, Pliny, Lucretius . . .  _passim_)?

Comment: @Draconis. Apologies. I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: "Ingenitus" (unbegotten) is the "proper attribute" of the Father--at least since Augustine's *De Trinitate*. I'm not aware of any serious discussion about whether the Holy Spirit is "born/unborn," though there certainly was concern about how the processions of the Son and Holy Spirit differed.

Comment: @brianpck. Geoges cites : Paul. Nol. carm. 1, 227 (Auct. class. ed. Mai 5, 379): Macedoniani spiritus sanctus, quem neque genitum neque ingenitum credimus.

Comment: @fdb Fair enough: "ingenitus" is proper to the Father, "genitus" is proper to the Son. So of course it makes sense to say the HS *isn't* either. I'm just being pedantic because I happened to have been studying a bunch of manuscripts dealing with trinitarian theology :)